# Activity Memory Leak reported by LeakCanary - WindowManagerGlobal

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-windowmanager, leakcanary

There is a memory leak reported by LeakCanary in my Android App. I have Googled and studied for days and cannot find any solution. The leaked object is an instance of Activity called "MakeFire". It seems to be related to android.view.WindowManagerGlobal. Can anyone point out how the leak happened, and how to fix it?

[Here is the LeakCanary ScreenCap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UERpl.png)

Here is the source code of the MakeFire Activity

```
public class MakeFire extends SharedMethod implements StatusBarFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
    DayTimeFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, BackButtonFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {


private Button firePlough;
private Button bowDrill;
private TextView makeFireWithBowDrillTime;
private TextView requirementTextview;
private Button performButton;

private String selectedButton;

private boolean firePloughOn;
private boolean bowDrillOn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_fire);

    firePlough = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firePlough);
    bowDrill = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bowDrill);
    makeFireWithBowDrillTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.makeFireWithBowDrillTime);
    requirementTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.requirementTextview);
    performButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.performButton);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    RefWatcher refWatcher = MyApplication.getRefWatcher(this);
    refWatcher.watch(this);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Bundle extra = new Bundle();
    extra.putString("classToGoBack", getClass().getName());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, InGameMenu.class);
    intent.putExtras(extra);
    startActivity(intent);
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    GameData.useImmersiveModeSticky(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
        //save on the latest save file
        FileOutputStream latestSavedGame = openFileOutput("latestSavedGame", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream latestGameData = new ObjectOutputStream(latestSavedGame);
        latestGameData.writeObject(GameData.GDI);
        latestSavedGame.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //TODO - delete it before uploading the app
        GameData.GDI.showPlainMsg("sharedMethodProblem!", this);
        final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw, true);
        e.printStackTrace(pw);
        GameData.GDI.showPlainMsg(sw.getBuffer().toString(), this);
    }
    boolean savedGameIsFine;
    try {
        FileInputStream latestSavedGame = openFileInput("latestSavedGame");
        ObjectInputStream latestGameData = new ObjectInputStream(latestSavedGame);
        savedGameIsFine = (latestGameData.readObject() != null);
        latestSavedGame.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        savedGameIsFine = false;
    }
    if (savedGameIsFine) {
        try {
            //save on the latest save file
            FileOutputStream latestSavedGame = openFileOutput("latestSavedGameBackup", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream latestGameData = new ObjectOutputStream(latestSavedGame);
            latestGameData.writeObject(GameData.GDI);
            latestSavedGame.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    } else {

    }
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    updateAllViews();
    requirementTextview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    performButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
//method for updating all amendable views in the page
private void updateAllViews() {
    //visibility of fire plough button
    if (GameData.GDI.anyThisInventoryAvailable(GameData.FIRE_PLOUGH) &&
            GameData.GDI.anyThisInventoryAvailable(GameData.TINDER) &&
            (!GameData.GDI.stormOn || GameData.GDI.currentLocation.campfireWindBlock)
            ) {
        firePlough.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.ic_fireplow_3_f,0,0);
        firePlough.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.buttonOnColour));
        firePloughOn = true;
    }
    else {
        firePlough.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.ic_fireplow_3_f_o,0,0);
        firePlough.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.buttonOffColour));
        firePloughOn = false;
    }
    //visibility of bow drill button
    if (GameData.GDI.bowDrillUnlocked) {
        bowDrill.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        makeFireWithBowDrillTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (GameData.GDI.anyThisInventoryAvailable(GameData.BOW_DRILL) &&
                GameData.GDI.anyThisInventoryAvailable(GameData.TINDER) &&
                (!GameData.GDI.stormOn || GameData.GDI.currentLocation.campfireWindBlock)
                ) {
            bowDrill.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.ic_bow_drill_3_f,0,0);
            bowDrill.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.buttonOnColour));
            bowDrillOn = true;
        }
        else {
            bowDrill.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.ic_bow_drill_3_f_o,0,0);
            bowDrill.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.buttonOffColour));
            bowDrillOn = false;
        }
    }
    updateStatusBarFragment();
    updateDayTimeFragment();
}

public void makeFireWithFirePlough(View view) {
    if (firePloughOn) {
        performButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        performButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    requirementTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    requirementTextview.setText(R.string.makeFireWithFirePloughRqm);
    selectedButton = "fire plough";
}
public void makeFireWithBowDrill(View view) {
    if (bowDrillOn) {
        performButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        performButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    requirementTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    requirementTextview.setText(R.string.makeFireWithBowDrillRqm);
    selectedButton = "bow drill";
}
public void perform(View view){
    if (!GameData.GDI.stormOn || GameData.GDI.currentLocation.campfireWindBlock){
        switch (selectedButton){
            case "fire plough":
                String msgToShow = "";
                String extraInfo = "";
                String[] timePassMsg;
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                //timepass method must run before the fireToLast method
                timePassMsg = GameData.GDI.timePass(30, 1, 1, 1, this);
                if (GameData.GDI.anyThisInventoryInBackpack(GameData.TINDER)) {
                    GameData.GDI.setInventoryAmount(GameData.TINDER, true, -1);
                }
                else {
                    GameData.GDI.setInventoryAmount(GameData.TINDER, false, -1);
                }
                extras.putString("toolUsed", getString(R.string.usedTinderMsg));
                //update tool durability
                GameData.GDI.firePloughDurability = GameData.GDI.updateInventoryDurability(GameData.FIRE_PLOUGH, GameData.GDI.firePloughDurability, GameData.FIRE_PLOUGH_MAX_DURABILITY);
                //Because in GameCamp.updateInventoryDurability, if the tool broke, it will reset the durability to its maxDurability;
                //so if these 2 numbers equal, the tool just broke
                if (GameData.GDI.firePloughDurability == GameData.FIRE_PLOUGH_MAX_DURABILITY) {
                    extraInfo += getString(R.string.firePloughBreakMsg) + "\n\n";
                }
                GameData.GDI.bowDrillUnlockCounter += 1;
                if (Math.random() < 0.75) {
                    GameData.GDI.currentLocation.fireOn = true;
                    GameData.GDI.currentLocation.fireToLast += 10;
                    msgToShow += getString(R.string.success) + "\n";
                    extras.putString("className", "Fire");
                }
                else {
                    msgToShow += getString(R.string.fail) + "\n";
                    if (!GameData.GDI.bowDrillUnlocked) {
                        if (GameData.GDI.bowDrillUnlockCounter >= 3) {
                            extraInfo += getString(R.string.bowDrillUnlockMsg) + "\n\n";
                            GameData.GDI.bowDrillUnlocked = true;
                            GameData.GDI.setCraftingAlertIcon(3);
                        }
                    }
                    extras.putString("className", "Make Fire");
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoadingPage.class);
                extras.putString("actionName", getString(R.string.makingFireWithFirePlough));
                extras.putInt("timeNeeded", 30);
                extras.putString("msgToShow", msgToShow);
                extras.putString("extraInfo", extraInfo);
                extras.putString("timePassMsg", timePassMsg[0]);
                extras.putString("deathReason", timePassMsg[1]);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case "bow drill":
                String msgToShow1 = "";
                String extraInfo1 = "";
                String[] timePassMsg1;
                Bundle extras1 = new Bundle();
                //timepass method must run before the fireToLast method
                timePassMsg1 = GameData.GDI.timePass(10, 1, 1, 1, this);
                if (GameData.GDI.anyThisInventoryInBackpack(GameData.TINDER)) {
                    GameData.GDI.setInventoryAmount(GameData.TINDER, true, -1);
                }
                else {
                    GameData.GDI.setInventoryAmount(GameData.TINDER, false, -1);
                }
                extras1.putString("toolUsed", getString(R.string.usedTinderMsg));
                //update tool durability
                GameData.GDI.bowDrillDurability = GameData.GDI.updateInventoryDurability(GameData.BOW_DRILL, GameData.GDI.bowDrillDurability, GameData.BOW_DRILL_MAX_DURABILITY);
                //Because in GameCamp.updateInventoryDurability, if the tool broke, it will reset the durability to its maxDurability;
                //so if these 2 numbers equal, the tool just broke
                if (GameData.GDI.bowDrillDurability == GameData.BOW_DRILL_MAX_DURABILITY) {
                    extraInfo1 += getString(R.string.bowDrillBreakMsg) + "\n\n";
                }
                if (Math.random() < 0.95) {
                    GameData.GDI.currentLocation.fireOn = true;
                    GameData.GDI.currentLocation.fireToLast += 10;
                    msgToShow1 += getString(R.string.success) + "\n";
                    extras1.putString("className", "Fire");
                }
                else {
                    msgToShow1 += getString(R.string.fail) + "\n";
                    extras1.putString("className", "Make Fire");
                }
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, LoadingPage.class);
                extras1.putString("actionName", getString(R.string.makingFireWithBowDrill));
                extras1.putString("className", "Fire");
                extras1.putInt("timeNeeded", 10);
                extras1.putString("msgToShow", msgToShow1);
                extras1.putString("extraInfo", extraInfo1);
                extras1.putString("timePassMsg", timePassMsg1[0]);
                extras1.putString("deathReason", timePassMsg1[1]);
                intent1.putExtras(extras1);
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        GameData.GDI.showPlainMsg(getString(R.string.cannotMakeFireInStormMsg), this);
    }
}
//fragment method
public void updateStatusBarFragment() {
    StatusBarFragment statusBarFragment = (StatusBarFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.statusBarFragment);
    statusBarFragment.updateStatusBar();
}
public void updateDayTimeFragment() {
    DayTimeFragment dayTimeFragment = (DayTimeFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.dayTimeFragment);
    dayTimeFragment.updateDayTimeView();
}
public void backButton(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Fire.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you have a static Context object ?

Comment: Oh sorry, that was for testing whether LeakCanary is working. It is now deleted. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. What are you doing in GameData.useImmersiveModeSticky(this); ?

Comment: To hide the navigation and notification bars. Here is the full content of the method:       activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

Comment: I'm hitting this too. Why is' Android's WindowManagerGlobal leaking my views?